# Strip_Tags + htmlentities - Sem conexão com a variavel

Tags: php, mysql, htmlentities

Estou com o seguinte problema.
Tenho uma conexão em banco de dados, que utiliza uma função chamada $FLD para trazer os campos que eu quiser:

```
$FLD="idfca, dtafca, solfca";
```

Após isso estou publicando o $FLD para uma variável:

```
var fld = "<? echo $FLD; ?>";
```

E dentro de um documento Ajax eu criei um loop para Scrool de página, e tentei conectar essa variável com o seguinte código:

```
$FLD = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['fld']));
```

Só que não está conectando, sendo que utilizei a mesma função para conectar a variável de loop no Javascript. Como eu resolvo?

Comment: Você está declarando uma variável em javascript ou em PHP no segundo exemplo? Se estiver usando javascript, favor informar, para eu poder adicionar a tag.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "não está conectando"?